# How to continuously fire filtering the table using keyRelease?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablerowsorter

I have module where I need to populate all the data in the `JTable`. Beside of having table user can able filter the data in table via searching on the textbox. I already setup the table and create function to populate the data to the table.

**Problem: Every time I type on the textbox the data on the table removed itself.**

**Goal: User can filter the data whatever they type on the textbox.**

**Here is example that I created already:**

[image: First Output]

**Here is what happen when I filter:**

[image: filtered]

**Here is the code:**

**Populate function:**

```
public void populatedoctor() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        
        Connection con;
        try {
            
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/health_check?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC","root","");
            
            String query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE role = '3' ";
            
            Statement sta = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = sta.executeQuery(query);
            
            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
            model.addColumn("First Name");
            model.addColumn("Last Name");
            model.addColumn("Phone Number");
            model.addColumn("Email");
            
            while(rs.next()) {
                model.addRow(new Object[] {
                        rs.getString("first_name"),
                        rs.getString("last_name"),
                        rs.getString("phone_number"),
                        rs.getString("email"),
                });
            }
            
            rs.close();
            sta.close();
            con.close();
            
            table.setModel(model);
            table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(200);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(200);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(200);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(200);
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Window Listener:**

```
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
            populatedoctor();
        }
    });
```

**TextBox:**

```
textField = new JTextField();
    textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

        @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e){
                
            String search_txt = textField.getText().toLowerCase();
            
            TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);
            
            table.setRowSorter(sorter);
            sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(search_txt));
        }

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            String search_txt = textField.getText().toLowerCase();
            
            TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);
            
            table.setRowSorter(sorter);
            sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(search_txt));
        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String search_txt = textField.getText().toLowerCase();
            
            TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);
            
            table.setRowSorter(sorter);
            sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(search_txt));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Don't use a KeyListener. Instead use a `DocumentListener`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for a working example.

Comment: @camickr do you have example snippet for this? thank you for the response.

Comment: @camickr I already apply what documentListener function has. but the problem is still same. I will edit the content

Comment: please see the updated content

Comment: *do you have example snippet for this?* - I gave you a link to the tutorial with a working example. The code you posted doesn't look like the code from the tutorial. Download the demo code and test it and make sure it does what you expect. Then compare the working code with your code to see what is different and fix the problem.

Comment: *"**Here is the code:**"* For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data for the table or source if from data available to the JRE (fonts, properties, Unicode characters, locales etc.).

Answer (score 0):

you can use your filter and the code on the KeyEvent !

```
String text = textField.getText();

sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(((model)));


    if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
        
        sorter.setRowFilter(null);
        
    } else {
        
        sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));
        
    }

    table.setRowSorter(sorter);
```